# How to enable HUD in OWASP ZAP after logging in

Tags: security, automated-tests, owasp, zap

I start the ZAP in Manual Explore mode with HUD enabled. I login to the page I'm testing but now all the HUD optionality is gone (as if HUD had been switched off)?

How do I switch the HUD back on at any time?

Answer (score 2):

The ZAP HUD can be turned on and off by a toolbar button on the ZAP desktop. If that is enabled then check to see if the ZAP add-ons are all up to date - new versions of webdrivers are regularly released and if you dont update them then that can cause these sort of problems.

Comment: I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the Windows WebDrivers Add-on but nothing changed.

Comment: Are there any errors shown in either th browser console log or the zap.log file? https://www.zaproxy.org/faq/somethings-not-working-what-should-i-do/#check-the-log-file

Comment: No, nothing in console or in the zap.log around the time of login.

Comment: And the HUD button on the toolbar is enabled? TBH I'm confused - I've never known the HUD not to work without something in the browser console log or zap.log.

Comment: It works initially, but after redirecting to a certain page, HUD switches off in the browser, while being enabled on the ZAP desktop.

Comment: Sounds like the HUD cannot cope with that redirect. Can you give any more details to enable us to reproduce this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not allowed to share details. Can you give me a specific example what I should be looking at?

Comment: Not easily no :P The HUD is pretty complicated. There are some docs on how it works here https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-hud/wiki/Initialization

Comment: Switching to Chrome resolved everything, seems to work much better there. Details: While disabling Firefox "Enhanced Tracking Protection" allowed some the HUD functionality, there were still issues. After reading other discussions, seems Firefox changes impacted HUD, where Chrome is still functional. I was able to complete the HUD "Page alerts History.js" tutorial with Firefox, but with Chrome I was able to complete the lesson, find the key which is part of the lesson of a HUD tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Firefox.  Make sure you turn off "enhanced tracking protection."

This can be done by clicking on the shield icon in in the URL bar and disabling "enhanced tracking protection".   If enabled, HUD does not work.

[image: Screenshot of verifying disabled enhance tracking protection]